# 'ss' command for checking sockets not found

Tags: linux, command-line, rhel

I get an error when I try to execute this command on Red Hat Linux.

```
$ ss -s
-bash: ss: command not found
```

It is supposed to be for checking socket statistics. How do I execute this?

Comment: Is the iproute package installed, are you root, or is /usr/sbin in your PATH?

Comment: ahh thanks... /usr/sbin/ss did the trick! thanks tink ;)

Comment: You're welcome :) ... can a comment be flagged as a solution? ;D

Comment: Ha I wish... if you transfer your comment as an answer ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per comment above: Try with the full path;

```
/usr/sbin/ss
```

Comment: `cannot access '/usr/sbin/ss': No such file or directory`

Answer (score 22):

```
sudo yum install iproute2   #RHEL
sudo apt install iproute2   #Ubuntu
```

Comment: While this was a possible answer to a similar problem it wasn't actually OP's problem which is hidden in the comments, as is the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Install it using `sudo yum install iproute`

Comment: This does not provide a solution to OP's problem.

Comment: To be fair, if the question is '*how do I execute `ss` when I'm getting "command not found"?*', and the `iproute` package contains the `ss` program, then this addresses the core of the question. It does not address possible $PATH issues or explain why they think this is the right answer, but it's a least an attempt to answer the question.

Comment: Hem, note my comments above and also the fact that this question was answered over 6 years ago and that answer was accepted. Did you intend this to be a complete answer, or as a comment on the other answer?

Comment: @jesse_b maybe this does not provide a solution to OP's problem, but this provides a solution to _my_ problem, and google lead me here. Unfortunately, this is how web works.